# What are the differences between a cover letter and an application letter?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application, application-cover-letter

I would like to apply for a PhD position, and I have found the following requirement in their web page:

An application letter that includes at least:

- contact information of the applicant
- the topics of interest in ranked order
- names and contact information of two senior academics available for reference per e-mail,
- information whether the application can be used in filling other vacancies at the Department and,
- from which source the applicant received the information regarding the current call.

I was thinking to put all these items in a list and fill them like some type of survey, but I am dubious if I should do that. I mean I have found templates for cover letters, but not for application letters. Is there any format for this?

Answer (score 1):

Good question, and has been something that I have been thinking about also.

Digging around, I found a few articles that may be of assistance, [This eHow article](http://www.ehow.com/info_8065585_application-letter-same-cover-letter.html) (Even though it is more trained towards work, rather than academia), and [thi about.com article](http://jobsearch.about.com/od/cover-letters/tp/types-of-cover-letters.htm).

Both links state that there are subtle differences - specifically, an application latter explains what qualifies you for the position/study, and the cover letter goes into more detail as to what qualifies you and explains your interests in the position/study.

I hope this helps (and best wishes with your application and studies!)